# Como fazer uma array com argumentos que possuem duas variáveis cada?

Tags: php

As linhas abaixo se repetem diversas vezes:

```
define("NS_CIRCULAR", 3068);
define("NS_CIRCULAR_TALK", 3069);
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_CIRCULAR] = "Circular";
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_CIRCULAR_TALK] = "Circular_talk";
$smwgNamespacesWithSemanticLinks[NS_CIRCULAR] = true;

define("NS_DESPACHO", 3070);
define("NS_DESPACHO_TALK", 3071);
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_DESPACHO] = "Despacho";
$wgExtraNamespaces[NS_DESPACHO_TALK] = "Despacho_talk";
$smwgNamespacesWithSemanticLinks[NS_DESPACHO] = true;
```

Para economizar linhas, é possível fazer uma array para "define", uma para "$wgExtraNamespaces" e uma para "$smwgNamespacesWithSemanticLinks" sem quebrar o php?

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se um array de define, mesmo que possível, fosse a melhor solução para isso.

Provavelmente seria o uso de ENUM, mas não recordo se o PHP teria.
Caso não tenha, uma solução próxima poderia ser criar uma classe com constant dentro.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
class enum
    {
    const X = 0;
    const Y = 1;
    const Z = 2;
    }

printf("Escreva Enum X:: %d\n", enum::X);
printf("Escreva Enum Y:: %d\n", enum::Y);
printf("Escreva Enum Z:: %d\n", enum::Z);
?>
```

Claro, existe diferenças entre define e const

Outra solução, que acho que cairia bem para o seu caso, seria o uso de array associativos.

```
<php
$enum = array
    (
    'X'=>0,
    'Y'=>1,
    'Z'=>2
    );

printf("Escreva Enum X:: %d\n", $enum['X']);
printf("Escreva Enum Y:: %d\n", $enum['Y']);
printf("Escreva Enum Z:: %d\n", $enum['Z']);
?>
```

Mesmo assim, se for manter os define, seria melhor que eles ficassem no topo do arquivo ou até mesmo em um arquivo separado só com Defines. Alinhados um embaixo do outro. Mais fácil de encontrar depois e mais organizado.

Comment: Ah, até com o nome da classe enum se poderia colocar class NS { suas constantes }, chamaria elas estaticamente, só ficaria mais organizado pelo fato de ser uma classe, mas acho que no contexto de uso seria semelhante ao define.